# Implementing a wrapping check box list or a tag list in Android

Tags: android

A standard list of check boxes takes up a lot of vertical real estate:

```
[ ] Option 1
[X] Opt 2
[X] Loooooong option 3
[ ] Option 4
```

What I would like to do is either wrap them:

```
[ ] Option 1 [X] Op 2 [X] Loooooong option
3 [ ] Option 4
```

Or something like the stackoverflow Tags field:

```
[X] Loooooong option 3 [X] Opt 2
Tags: [ Optio       ]
        Option 1
        Option 4
```

I've not been able to find a suitable class to do that, and I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. As each field will have different lengths (for example, contact names) using a TableLayout or GridView doesn't make sense.